# Which of the two sum calculations in Matlab / Octave is optimal on a row vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, octave, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I'm fairly to Matlab / Octave and Machine learning, but so far I've learned you want to avoid iterative loops for summation and vectorize as much as possible.

Given a row vector like: `x = [ 1,2,3,4,5]`

You can calculate the sum with these two methods:

- `sum(x)`
- `x * ones(length(x),1)`

While my gut tells me to us the built in functions, the second options feels more 'vectorized'.

Which of the is more optimal and why?  Are there tradeoffs between the two in performance vs. memory use, etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it seems like `sum` is better: the time/memory overhead of allocating the "all ones" vector does not worth it.
However, when one needs to repeatedly sum over vectors of the same length, the allocation of the vector can be done only once, thus reducing the average overhead.

On my machine:

"Caching" the all ones vector:

```
N=100;T=500000; x=rand(T,N);
tic;o=ones(N,1);for ii=1:T, x(ii,:)*o;end;toc
```

> Elapsed time is **0.480388** seconds.

While using `sum`:

```
tic;for ii=1:T, sum(x(ii,:));end;toc
```

> Elapsed time is **0.488517** seconds.

So, it's *slightly* faster to use the "all ones" vector method in case of repeated sums.

---

If you take the allocation of the "all ones" vector out of the [time calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255838/which-of-the-two-sum-calculations-in-matlab-octave-is-optimal-on-a-row-vector/36266304#comment60160546_36266304), you end up with:

```
N=100;T=500000; x=rand(T,N);o=ones(N,1);
tic;for ii=1:T, x(ii,:)*o;end;toc
```

> Elapsed time is **0.477762** seconds.

But again, you'll have to allocate it at some point...

Comment: good point.  I'm explicitly allocating the one's vector at the time of the calculation, if memory isn't a concern, pre-allocating and reusing the ones vector might yeild boost with repetitive computation

Comment: if you pull the time to create the ones out of the computation what does your elapsed time for the one's  version cost in elapsed time?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, did some more digging:

From a performance standpoint the built in `sum()` is much better:

```
  x = rand(1,100000000); 
  %slowwwww
  t = cputime; x * ones(length(x),1); e= cputime - t; e

  % Faster
  t = cputime; sum(x); e= cputime - t; e
```

I guessing using an extra vector of ones is also needless memory use.  Since there is no performance gain over `sum()` the non-native method is far less optimal.

Comment: `sum` is definitely faster.  The extra memory and time required for creating the `ones` will slow things down.

Comment: Why don't you compare "x * ones(length(x),1)" with "x * sum(x)"? I thought you want to compare to "sum(x)". Nevertheless sum is much faster. Have a look at the "extra" flag for sum which uses a different algorithm than just "+=" in a for loop: http://hg.octave.org/octave/file/tip/liboctave/operators/mx-inlines.cc#l1354

Comment: s/don't/do ... I've inverted the question

Comment: @Ray since creating `ones(1,numel(x))` is mem/time consuming, it is still interesting to compare multiple `sum` operations on vectors of the same size, when `ones` is only allocated once for all the sums...

Comment: @Shai that is an interesting scenario indeed. I think the OP should create this vector once and invoke matrix vector multiplication as the portion to be timed. I'm curious to see if this will be faster than sum. If a proper timing framework was used (i.e. `timeit`) we may see the slow down happening due to the constant allocation and calls to `ones` in the timed code. If this allocation is performed only once, we may see some better time comparisons. Currently `sum` is faster because of just one call, but repeated calls and then finding some sort of average may provide better insight.